# Performing CUDA in LabVIEW

Tags: cuda, gpu, labview

I want to perform CUDA operation in LabVIEW to transfer multiple files in GPU in parallel and then perform arithmetic operations on GPU and then save the data in new file. I learnt that in order to perform operations in GPU, we need to create a DLL file and then import it to LabVIEW but I don't know how. Can you give me some example of a similar operation?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the link that you might find interesting:
[LabVIEW GPU Computing](https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-6064)

Answer (score 2):

LabVIEW has no support of CUDA, as you said. Calling DLL in LabVIEW is quite easy, Use the [Call Library Function node](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361F-01/glang/call_library_function/) for this purpose.

Even easier, once you've written the dll, have LabVIEW generate VI wrappers around your DLL by entering the wizard in Tools menu -> Import -> Shared library

See also [this article](https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-9076) that explains things quite extensively.

Comment: But I am not able to make a dll file to be imported from LabView. Can you plz explain the way to do it or if you have a sample code, can you plz share it with me? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have time to write code for you. You can find a lot of references on the [link I added](https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-9076) to my answer. If you have problems come back here to get some help!

Answer (score 0):

NI should also has a set of CUDA VIs available on their site. I don't know if those would help in your case, since you already seem to have the C code, but it might.

Comment: Do you have a link to these VI's?

Comment: Ya NI has got some CUDA VIs but that is insufficient, I can just add arrays into the GPU but now I want to do operations on those array data and I am finding it difficult. Can you help me out plz..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, NI can provide support. Please join this [community group](https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-6064). There is a library that you can install so you can have CUDA support in LabVIEW. Also, please post questions to this community group for help if needed.